# Как сделать упорядочивание после группировки?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Мне нужно получить модель с лучшим индексом, но после группировки пишет ошибку:

```
dbContext.TrainingObjects
  .GroupBy(e => e.ApplicationUserId)
  .Select(e => new { e.Key, Max = e.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Index).FirstOrDefault() })
```

Но пишет ошибку:

```
 .OrderByDescending(a => a.Index)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

Не очень понимаю, как можно сделать сортировку по Index после GroupBy??

Comment: Вы группируете по одному полю, а потом хотите сортировать по другому полю? Ну вот представьте - одному e.ApplicationUserId соответствует в двух записях два разных a.Index... какое из двух использовать в сортировке?

Comment: @Akina
Я группирую по e.ApplicationUserId, А потом сортирую по a.Index, И беру запись с самым высоким Indexом, вот это только и надо

Comment: *Я группирую по e.ApplicationUserId, А потом сортирую по a.Index* Ещё раз ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО прочитайте то, что я написал...

Comment: @Akina, Не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду под 'соответствует в двух записях два разных a.Index'? 
Если эта одна таблица, то индекс по идеи должен быть один.

Тогда по вашей, логике и Sum работать не должен,  как он может считать сумму, если это будет 2 разных "Индекса" или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вы группируете по e.ApplicationUserId. Его значение в пределах таблицы не уникально, повторяется, есть несколько разных записей с одним и тем же значением. Верно?

Comment: @Akina, Да верно

Comment: Ну теперь представьте. У Вас есть три записи с e.ApplicationUserId=1000, у них Index равны 1, 10 и 100. Группировка объединяет эти три записи в одну группу, т.е. одну группированную запись. Вопрос - какое из трёх значений взять для этой объединённой записи, чтобы потом использовать при сортировке?

Comment: @Akina, Я чувствую себя очень глупо. Но я не понимаю, зачем нам брать одну из этих записей, мы берем столбик (параметр) и по него сортируем. А после берем первый элемент

Comment: Нет. Всё с точностью до наоборот. Сначала - группировка, потом - взятие максимального значения в группе (при этом образуется новое поле, которое отсутствует в исходной структуре!), и только затем - сортировка по этому новому полю.

Comment: Или, если нужна из всей таблицы одна запись, с самым большим значением - тогда группировка не нужна вообще. Тогда нужна только сортировка, а затем извлечение только самой первой записи из полученного сортированного набора.

Comment: Нужно группировка, и взятие для каждого e.ApplicationUserId самого большего Index.
Так что группировка необходима( С ней больше всего проблем

Comment: @Akina, Тогда не очень понимаю, как надо сделать. Чтобы нормально.

Сортировку вперед сделать, и брать сразу первый элемент?

Comment: *Нужно ... взятие для каждого e.ApplicationUserId самого большего Index.* Тогда именно то, что я сказал. Сначала группировка по `ApplicationUserId`, потом получение `MAX(Index) AS max_index` (с присвоением полю нового имени `max_index`). И затем вывод полученного поля. Если надо - с сортировкой по нему, с использованием присвоенного нового имени. Т.е. при получении максимального значения для группы никакой сортировки нет, это именно взятие максимального значения в группе. Внутри для этого, конечно, будет использоваться сортировка - но так это внутри, явно сортировку указывать не надо.

Comment: @Akina, Вы правы работает. СПАСИБО!